# How can I dynamically add and remove ASP:DropDownLists?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to be able to have a clickable button that dynamically adds dropdown lists that pull their values from a databinder. My problem is that it looks like ASP.Net is attempting to parse the dropdown list before the Javascript and is complaining about the ID.

This is the error I am getting:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: 'ddlToolPusher' + i + '' is not a valid identifier. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: 'ddlToolPusher' + i + '' is not a valid identifier. --->
```

Here is what I have:

**ascx**

```
<div id="dropdowns">
    Toolpushers:
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlToolPusher" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" />
</div>
<p><a href="#" id="addDD">add something</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var ddlDiv = $('#dropdowns');
    var i = 1;
    $('#addDD').click(function() {
        $('<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlToolPusher' + i + '" />').appendTo(ddlDiv);
        i++;
        return;
    });    
});
</script>
```

**ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();
    rmModuleNavigationWrapper.InnerHtml = Helper.BuildModuleNavigation();
    btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonHandler);

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }


}

protected void BindData()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("robinson_GetEmployeesForRigDDL", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlToolPusher.DataSource = reader;
        ddlToolPusher.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlToolPusher.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlToolPusher.DataBind();
        ddlToolPusher.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose One", "0"));
        ddlToolPusher.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code here:

```
   $('#addDD').click(function() {
    $('<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlToolPusher' + i + '" />').appendTo(ddlDiv);
    i++;
```

This code is evaluated on the **BROWSER** and will not be converted into HTML elements.  You can only build DOM elements using jQuery/javascript etc... you cannot add/modify ASP markup using it.

You should be adding javascript or jQuery to add items to a SELECT list via a AJAX call etc...  What you have will not work EVER.

Answer (score 1):

`asp:DropDownLists` are converted to html select/option tags.  If you are trying to add list items client side you have to do it using client side style coding add `<option>` to `<select>`

And this will not persist.  Once you post back the dynamically added options will be gone

Comment: @TMckeown...oops looks like you hit enter first...apologies